# QUnit can't recognize more than one test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, qunit

I am having a problem with QUNIT, no matter what I seem to do the test suites will only ever recognize one test or module, even though I have multiple one's in the javascript. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
    <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
            QUnit.log = function(result, message)
            {
                if (window.console && window.console.log)
                {
                   window.console.log(result +' :: '+ message);
                }   
            }
            module("Basic Unit Test");
            test("Sample test", function()
            {
                expect(1);
                equal(divide(4,2),2, 'Expected 2 as the result, result was ' + divide(4,2));
            });
                        test("Test two", function() {
                        expect(1);
                        equal(divide(8,2),2,'Expected 4 as the result, result was ' + divide(8,2));
                        });

            function divide(a,b){
                return a / b;
            }
          });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You probably have QUnit-Url-Parameters in the Url which restrict testing to the modules / tests specified in these filter params (on http://docs.jquery.com/Qunit see "URL Parameters"). Start with a clean URL and then all your tests should be executed.

eg. Your URL contains `blah.html?testNumber=1`. This means only one test will run. Remove `?testNumber=1`.

Answer (score 28):

Earlier when you were setting it up, you clicked on "Rerun". This quietly added a "?testNumber=1" to your URL that excludes all other tests from being run.

Frustrating how quiet that is.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, THANK YOU for a clear, precise answer. This has been killing me for 20 minutes!

Comment: Was frustrating but became interesting once I started playing with the numbers ?testNumber=1,2,3... Interestingly it only executes the particular test case with whatever number I pass :) Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [sample page that will run more then one test](https://gist.github.com/2906762)

It contain the two tests you put here.